# "The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for function 'AND()' in process Builder in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, processbuilder

I am trying to use 'Formula evaluates to true' criteria in Process Builder.Following is my Formula Expression.But on trying to save the criteria it is showing following error::"The formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for function 'AND()'. Expected Boolean, received Number". Please Help.

AND ( [De_Dupe__c].Applicant__c.CIBIL_Score__c= '-2',[De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.Loan_Amount__c<100,000,000,
               OR (
                      AND ( [De_Dupe__c].PAN__c = [De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.PAN_Number__c,
                    TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'RBI',
                                     TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'SMA',
                    TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'Compliance',
                    TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'Legal',
                    TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'Fraud',
                    TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Source_Or_Target__c )<>'Target' 
                    ),
          [De_Dupe__c].PAN__c<>[De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.PAN_Number__c 
        ) , 
                  [De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.Sourcing_Channel__c.Name='NJ Wealth'
               )

Comment: here in the statement : [De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.Sourcing_Channel__c.Name='NJ Wealth' is De_dupe__c has related object  Loan application and loan application having related child object Sourcing_Channel__c?.. I need to write similar formula, thats why asking, if this syntax works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the bold part below. I think you need to remove commas from the number:

AND ( [De_Dupe__c].Applicant__c.CIBIL_Score__c= '-2',[De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.Loan_Amount__c<**100,000,000**, OR (
AND ( [De_Dupe__c].PAN__c = [De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.PAN_Number__c, TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'RBI', TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'SMA', TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'Compliance', TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'Legal', TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Dedupe_Source__c )<>'Fraud', TEXT ( [De_Dupe__c].Source_Or_Target__c )<>'Target' ), [De_Dupe__c].PAN__c<>[De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.PAN_Number__c ) , [De_Dupe__c].Loan_Application__c.Sourcing_Channel__c.Name='NJ Wealth' )